# Making a slideshow fit the screen

Tags: html, css

I am developing a front-end website using bootstrap. I have inserted a slideshow but it doesn't fit the screen. I have inserted the image into the HTML, not into the CSS. Here is my code:

```
    <div class="container-fluid" id="background">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="slideShow">
                <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <!-- Indicators -->
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>

                    </ol>

                    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                      <div class="item active">
                          <img src="pics/happiness1.jpg" alt="Happiness" class="slideShow">
                      </div>

                      <div class="item">
                          <img src="pics/happiness2.jpg" alt="Happiness" class="slideShow">
                      </div>

                      <div class="item">
                          <img src="pics/happiness3.jpg" alt="Happiness" class="slideShow">
                      </div>

                      <div class="item">
                          <img src="pics/happiness4.jpg" alt="Happiness" class="slideShow">
                      </div>

                      <div class="item">
                          <img src="pics/happiness5.jpg" alt="Happiness" class="slideShow">
                      </div>  
                    </div>

                    <!-- Left and right controls -->
                    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                    </a>
              </div>

        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

How to make those images fit to the screen?

Comment: Do you want the slideshow to just fit the page width or fit the page height as well?

Comment: I want the slideshow to fit the page width only.

Answer (score 1):

Append this last of your css file ..

```
.carousel-inner>.item>a>img, .carousel-inner>.item>img, .img-responsive, .thumbnail a>img, .thumbnail>img{
   min-height: 100vh;
}
```